# mounted veracrypt container switches to read only

Tags: 20.04, permissions, veracrypt

Pro's,

I already upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 a couple of months ago using Veracrypt there. Before I used Ubuntu 18.04 in the same way.

For a couple of days I have had the following problem:

- I can open the container and can open, save and copy files inside the mounted container.
- Then after 20-40 minutes everything is locked.
- It's still possible to open but not to write anything in the container.
- I get e.g. the message: "Permissions do not allow pasting files in this directory"
- Although ls -la reveals the permissions: "drwx------"
- Then if I unmount and mount it again, I can again write for a while.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: Check your veracrypt settings.  There's an option to relock the drive after a certain time period

Comment: I did not find such an option. Now I just created a new container and copied the files into it. I'll see if it works

Comment: Unfortunately I do have the problem with the new container as well. @ThomasWard I checked all preferences and the default mount parameters and did not find anything like a relock. Where do I find it? (Btw: I'm using the current veracrypt version 1.24 Update 7)